# Is there a typesafe way to work with rowCause?

Tags: apex, api, apex-managed-sharing, sharing-rule, type

On the project I'm currently working with, we have Apex Sharing Rules.
I see we are passing rowCause as a String everywhere.
But the values of these Strings look like API names.

Is there a typesafe way we can work with these?

Answer (score 6):

Refer this documentation: [Sharing a Record Using Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_bulk_sharing_creating_with_apex.htm)

Apex sharing reasons are defined on an object's detail page. Each Apex sharing reason has a label and a name:

- *The label displays in the Reason column when viewing the sharing for a record in the user interface. This label allows users and administrators to understand the source of the sharing. The label is also enabled for translation through the Translation Workbench.*
- The name is used when referencing the reason in the API and Apex.

All Apex sharing reason names have the following format:
`MyReasonName__c`

Apex sharing reasons can be referenced programmatically as follows:

```
Schema.CustomObject__Share.rowCause.SharingReason__c
```

For example, an Apex sharing reason called Recruiter for an object called Job can be referenced as follows:

```
Schema.Job__Share.rowCause.Recruiter__c
```

> So, sharing reason must be used which you have defined and that's why it takes API name. It always hold String value.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I think you missed the point of the question... I want to know if there is a typesafe way to work with rowCause.  For example, if I pass the value of rowCause from one method to another, could I create a method private void doSomething(RowCause rowCause) { /* do whatever */} which won't accept strings which are not valid rowcauses, and to which I can only pass a valid rowCause by using its API name.

Comment: @BrianKessler But the direct answer to that question is a simple "No", which doesn't add a lot of value for anyone. Both Santanu's and Charles' answers seem to me to illuminate different aspects of how you *can* get some level of compile- and run-time validation of the use of row cause values.

Comment: I appreciate the additional information, but I also appreciate directness.  Of course nothing says the two need be mutually exclusive.  :-)  Anyway, I'll leave this question just in case some-else knows a way to make that a "Yes".

Answer (score 3):

Just to test out... I created a sharing reason for a test object and ran the following line in Developer Console:

```
System.debug(Schema.MyObj__Share.rowCause.MyCause__c instanceof String);
```

I got back the error *Operation instanceof is always true since an instance of String is always an instance of String*. So that tells me it returns a String and not some special type.

However if you want to validate that it's a proper RowCause, you can do:

```
List<Schema.PicklistEntry> rowCauses = MyObj__Share.rowCause.getDescribe().getPicklistValues();
```

The results you get back will include all the custom row causes and the standard allowable ones too.